# Grid Pattern / Wrinkles

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers

Want to achieve similar blanket Marked as "?". How to make grid bumps with wrinkle after the cloth simulation & baking etc?

[image]

Comment: You can use multiple displacement modifiers. One for the grid,  and  other for the wrinkles.

Answer (score 3):

Even a single displacement could work, perhaps, with a specially crafted displacement image, like this:

I just created this in Gimp, quickly but you get the idea.

[image]

Note: it has a black border, to displace the squares, and a white/grey pattern to displace the cloth texture.

When using two separate displacements (two images) you could set their influence separately in Blender, though, with my single image relative displacement weights are set by the image shades (black maximum, grey intermediate, white none).

a quick test:

[image]

Comment: [Displace](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html) modifier (like *Normal* option in texture settings in Blender Internal) uses *grey* as 0 influence, while black and white - maximum values, where black - for intruding, white - for protruding.

Comment: ? so...what color is making the cloth texture (not the "grid", but what is inside the squares), in my quick example? If white and grey are both evaluated 0 influence, shouldn't the squares appear completely flat?

Comment: White is not 0 influence; it's *maximum* for protruding, i.e. by default it'll affect geometry to [go up and black - down](http://i.imgur.com/Alg5eZ0.jpg); grey will be 0. In your example white parts of clouds make the geometry become moved up, wihle grey parts make adjacent geometry leave as is (roughly). If you would set there black color instead of grey the effect of bump would be more visible.